# How to recover memories from the Feywild?

Tags: dnd-5e, feywild

Session 1 of my campaign is going to be the group waking up in an open field with no memory of why or how they got there. Later on in the campaign I want them to recover these lost memories. These lost memories are from the Feywild. Is there any RAW way of recovering these memories?

Comment: I just found the answer in the DMG. Just needed  to read a bit further. If possible can a mod delete this question. Thank you

Comment: You can delete your own question by clicking the "delete" link beneath the tags.

Comment: If you found a good answer, it might be valuable to post it here, rather than delete the question.

Comment: Indeed. Per the SO blog: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). If you have found the answer, it's better to share it with others rather than keep it to yourself! Also: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. :)

Answer (score 6):

## Remove Curse

Page 50 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* includes a optional rule for the Feywild plane on memory loss. It has creatures that fail a saving throw upon leaving lose their memories of time spent on that plane. However, it end with the line:

> Any spell that can end a curse can restore the creature's
> lost memories.

The most obvious spell which ends curses is [*remove curse*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/remove-curse) (A 3rd level abjuration spell available to Clerics, Paladins, Warlocks, and Wizards):

> At your touch, all curses affecting one creature or object end.